# syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO rest_tables(0,TABLENUMBER) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table using sqlite in Android studio, but when I click the button that adds the data to the table I am getting this error.

```
07-22 14:19:01.836 23818-23818/com.example.user.restapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: rest_tables
07-22 14:19:01.851 23818-23818/com.example.user.restapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Tablenumber=2 Taken=0
07-22 11:12:20.576 21924-21924/com.example.user.restapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "0": syntax error
07-22 11:12:20.596 21924-21924/com.example.user.restapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting 0=0 TABLENUMBER=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO rest_tables(0,TABLENUMBER) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1462)
        at com.example.user.restapp.DatabaseHelper.InsertData(DatabaseHelper.java:39)
```

Here is the **DatabaseHelper** class:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "rest_tables";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "TABLENUMBER";
    public static final String TAKEN = "0";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TABLENUMBER TEXT,TAKEN TEXT)");
           // db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean InsertData(String tablenumber,String taken)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,tablenumber);
        contentValues.put(TAKEN,taken);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

And in the OnClickListener for the button in the MainActivity class I wrote:

```
boolean isInserted = myDB.InsertData("2","0");
                if(isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Not Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly is causing this error ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public static final String TAKEN = "0";
> ```

...

> ```
> contentValues.put(TAKEN,taken);
> ```

`0` is not a valid column name, That's the immediate reason for the syntax error.

A column name corresponding to your schema would be `"TAKEN"` and not `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public  SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

public  DataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
{
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
public  DataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close() 
{
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public boolean InsertData(String tablenumber,String taken)
    {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("TABLENUMBER",tablenumber);
        contentValues.put("TAKEN",taken);
         db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
```

and in your main activity:

```
//if statement
    DataBaseAdapter.InsertData(f2","0");
                        Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Data save successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Never insert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: I changed the code and I am still getting the same error. The logcat is saying that the error is in these two lines of code: `long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);` `boolean isInserted = myDB.InsertData("2","0");` I also noticed that the logcat is saying: No such table

Comment: @Hussein thats because your `isInserted` is a `boolean` which only accepts true or false answers. So i would suggest you change it to a String or Integer and make an if statement to say if data is successfully inserted then `isinserted = true`

Comment: @Hussein check the answer, it might help